# Sun's and planets' inclination to the Invariable plane

Tags: orbit, solar-system, orbital-mechanics

What are the inclinations of all major Solar system planets (Mercury to Pluto) to the invariable plane? Looking for accurate data calculated on them.

Also, What is the inclination of the Sun to the invariable plane? Since Sun revolves around the barycenter.

If a planet has an inclination to the invariable plane, that means at any point in time the degree is different depending on the planet's position. where can I get this information of planets' inclination degree at any date? Calculated by NASA JPL Horizon?